# Observing warnings when integrating elasticsearch cluster with AD

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

We have a cluster running with docker with multiple nodes. The cluster is a licensed cluster and we recently enabled TLS security on the cluster. We have enabled TLS security for node-to-node communication. We used self signed certificate for the same which we generated using the Elasticsearch cert util.
Along with built-in users, we also made a custom user to ingest data via Logstash. The cluster was working fine and ingesting data was working properly at this point.

After this, we enabled the Active Directory integration using rolling restart. AD integration was successful and AD users are able to login into cluster as expected, but following warning message started to observe in elasticsearch node logs:

```
"log.level": "WARN", "message":"Authentication to realm <realm-name> failed - authenticate failed (Caused by LDAPException(resultCode=49 (invalid credentials), diagnosticMessage='80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090439, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4563\u0000', ldapSDKVersion=6.0.3, revision=405ee52a554f9867e81d4598a5b2f97beabeb29a))", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[<node-name>][generic][T#23]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.RealmsAuthenticator","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"mOT5UswFSnelOojKdBtypQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"4GYo6RyCQ6aT3I9j4c-YWQ","elasticsearch.node.name":"<node-name>","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"<cluster-name>"}
```

Log ingestion is working fine but the above warning message is shown continuously, can anyone please suggest to fix this warning message.

Comment: Does this help? https://discuss.elastic.co/t/authentication-to-realm-ldap1-failed-authenticate-failed/270907

Comment: Well Actually if my integration was wrong then the AD credentials should not work but I am able to login perfectly with both AD creds and default native users. And the native user which I created was also ingesting data correctly with logstash. And I am not receiving an error I am receiving a warning.

Comment: I then also changed the order of the realm change. I initially had AD realm order as 0. then I changed the order of the AD realm to 1 and added the native user authentication realm order as 0. But still I was receiving that error.